# Separable first order differential equivalence: how can I get expected outcome?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am told a colony at any time has a population at time $t$ according to the rule:

$$\frac{dB}{dt} = kB + I$$

Where $B$ is the colony size, $k$ is a positive constant, and $I$ is some constant. I want to show that the colony size at any time $t$ is:

$$B(t) = \frac{1}{k}(Ae^{kt}-I)$$

Where $A = \pm e^C$.

Here's my work so far:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{dB}{dt} &= kB+I \\
dB &= (kB+I)\ dt \\
\frac{dB}{kB+I} &= 1\ dt \\
\int \frac{dB}{kB+I} &= \int 1\ dt \\
\ln |kB+I| &= t + C \\
e^{\ln |kB+I|} &= e^{t+C} \\
|kB+I| &= e^{t+C} \\
&= e^t e^C \\
kB+I &= Ae^t \\
kB &= Ae^t - I \\
B &= \frac{1}{k}(Ae^t - I)
\end{align}$$

Note the exponent $k$ is missing from the right side. I'm not particularly sure what I'm meant to be doing here, other than showing equivalence:

$$\frac{dB}{dt} = kB+I \equiv B(t) = \frac{1}{k}(Ae^{kt}-I)$$

What are the steps to show this?

Comment: I believe you have shown what you set out to; simply rearrange the last line

Comment: It looks like you have a complete answer here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is between the fourth and fifth line of your work.
$$
\int \frac{dB}{kB+I} = \frac1k \ln |kB+I|
$$
The $\frac1k$ was left out in your work. (To see why it's there, simply do a *u* substitution with *u=kB+I*).

From there onward, your work is all correct. Just carry the $k$ through each step and you will arrive at the desired expression.